# area plot function

Tags: matlab, plot

I've been trying to use the MATLAB 'area' plotting function (filled line plot) however when I plot with a log y-scale, the plot is just a line with no "fill". Am I missing something here?

Comment: You'd better post your code here.

Comment: @herohuyongtao here is a short code example that shows the problem...

    `a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]   
    b = [1 0.1 0.0001 3 0.3 3000 500 10]   
    figure   
    area(a,b)   
    set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')`

Comment: This post on the MATLAB Google Group shows the same problem....   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/JVNEuoObBSE

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the y-coordinates of your area are very big. If you have a look to the log function, the values above 1 are heavily shrunk.

[image]

Thus, the y-side of your area goes from a segment to a point. If you try to zoom a lot in the y-axis, you may see the area as a rectangle instead of a line.